# Reflection: create object of class with interface

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to write a generic method to insert json data into the database. I get the object (different classes) created. However, I can not pass it to the next method, because compiler says, it is not of type 'MyInterface', which the class implements. Is there a way to cast the obj to it's real class (dynamically evaluating the current class)? Or turn of compiler error checking for this method? Or any other idea?

```
public static int updateDBObjectJson(Uri uri, Class dbObject, String json) {
    int changedEntries = 0;
    if (json.length() > 5) {
        try {
            JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(json);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArr.length(); i++) { // no for each available
                JSONObject jObj = jArr.optJSONObject(i);

                Constructor ct = dbObject.getConstructor(JSONObject.class);
                Object obj = ct.newInstance(jObj);

                // update DB
--> does not compile: boolean changed = upsertEntry(uri, obj, false);
--> correct answer:   boolean changed = upsertEntry(uri, (MyInterface) obj, false);
                if (changed)
                    changedEntries++;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            ILog.e("JSON Error: " + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ILog.e(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do the objects all implement `MyInterface`? Than just cast it.

Comment: It is possible to dynamically implement an interface, using the Java Reflection Proxy mechanism. But I am not sure that this is what you need; as I am really puzzled on what your real problem is ...

Comment: Year, real stupid. (MyInterface) obj works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics will help here to do it type-safely:

```
public static int updateDBObjectJson(..., Class<? extends MyInterface> dbObject, ...) {
    ...
    JSONObject jObj = jArr.optJSONObject(i);

    Constructor<? extends MyInterface> ct = dbObject.getConstructor(JSONObject.class);
    MyInterface obj = ct.newInstance(jObj);
    ...
    boolean changed = upsertEntry(uri, obj, false);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nice! Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that the class implements the interface that you need, add a check and cast:

```
Object tmp = ct.newInstance(jObj);
if (!(tmp instanceof MyInterface)) {
    // Throw an exception that you did not expect this to happen
}
// This will succeed because of the check above
MyInterface obj = (MyInterface)tmp;
// update DB
boolean changed = upsertEntry(uri, obj, false);
```